# Manipulating Strings in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I'm building an app that calculates the number of days between two dates. When I print the result to the console I get some code included which I want to remove from the result:

[image]

I'm trying to remove the unwanted code by splitting the string, using 'componentsSeparatedByString'.

However, in order to use this method I have to first convert the 'components' constant to an NSString. When I try to do this I get an error message: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSString' with an argument list of type '(string: NSDateComponents)'

```
@IBAction func calculateDays(sender: AnyObject) {

    let start = String(firstSelectedDate.text!)
    let end = String(secondSelectedDate.text!)

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!
    let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end)!

    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unit:NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.NSDayCalendarUnit

    let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])


    let newComponents = NSString(string: components) // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSString' with an argument list of type '(string: NSDateComponents)'

    let componentsArray = newComponents?.componentsSeparatedByString("<NSDateComponents: 0x7f91aaf29980>")

    print(componentsArray[1])
```

Would be very grateful if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the `components` variable you can retrieve the `day` property, try this instead:

```
let start = "2010-09-01"
let end = "2010-09-08"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end)!

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
print(components.day) // 7
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you so much, Victor!